# MySQL IF function with multiple expressions

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am new to MySQL statements, so bear with me.

I am working with a single table that contains 3 columns.
ID, value, and report ID.

What I am looking to do is update the 'value' to yes of id = 2 WHEN the value is 'yes' for id = 1, and at the same time matching the report id is matching between id 1 and id 2. Apologies if this doesn't make sense, please let me know if I need to clarify better.

### Here are some queries I've attempted so far:

```
UPDATE table
    SET value = CASE WHEN value = 'Yes' AND id = 1 AND report_id LIKE report_id 
THEN 'Yes' ELSE value END
    WHERE (id = 2 or id = 1);
```

---

```
UPDATE table 
SET value = 'Yes'     
WHERE (report_id = report_id     
AND value = 'Yes')     
AND id = 1     
 OR id = 2;
```

---

```
UPDATE table
SET value = IF(value = 'Yes' AND report_id LIKE report_id AND id = 1, 'Yes', '')
WHERE id = 2;
```

Example Table:

| id | value | report_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 1001 |
| 1 | no | 1002 |
| 1 | yes | 1003 |
| 2 |  | 1001 |
| 2 |  | 1002 |
| 3 | cat | 1001 |
| 5 |  | 1002 |

Comment: `report_id LIKE report_id` will always be true -- everything is always like itself. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: If you're trying to compare `report_id` between two different rows, you need to join the table with itself.

Comment: I am trying to compare report_id between two different rows, making sure they are identical. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your conditions are being processed on a single row, not comparing the `id=1` rows to the `id=2` rows with the same `report_id`.

You can use a self-join to compare different rows of the table with a relationship.

You don't need `CASE`, you can select the rows to update using the `WHERE` conditions.

```
UPDATE t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.report_id = t2.report_id
SET t1.value = 'yes'
WHERE t1.id = 2 AND t2.id = 1 AND t2.value = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, please try to use something like below to get the result. You need to use the same table in exists condition as well. I hope my answer helps you.

```
update table t set t.value = 'Yes' where exists ( select 1 from table t1 where 
    t1.value = 'Yes' and t1.id = 1 and t.report_id = t1.report_id) and t.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
  table a 
  JOIN table b ON a.report_id = b.report_id 
SET 
  a.value = 'Yes' 
WHERE 
  a.id = 2 
  AND b.id = 1 
  AND b.value = 'Yes';
```